# Scrolling animation from on specific spot to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, translate

Let's say i have a box and it's offset from the correct spot by `tranform:translateX(-200px)` [image: offset to the left]

Example below pic has two `<section>`'s, one is the large grey box and other white containing the `.box` in red. The illustration shows where/how the animation should move only as the viewer scrolls and contentiously move `.box` back and forth from `-200px` to `0px`.

[image: user controls the <code>.box</code>]

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){

  $(window).scroll(function(){

    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    var greySection = $('.grey').height(); // Which is 800px high
  
    // (what other variables, and functions could I add? )
  
    if( wScroll > greySection /1.3 ) // 1.3 of section.grey is where i want the animation to start 
      $('.box').css('transform','translateX(' + /* (what do i put here?) */ + 'px)');
  
    });
  
});
```

```css
.grey{  /* for visual purposes */
  background-color: grey;
}

section {
  width:100%;
  height:800px;
}

p{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

.box{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:0 auto; /* Here is where the box position should end up */
  transform:translateX(-200px); /* Control this property to move box */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="grey">
  <p>Some contents here. Ignore this section</p>
</section>

<section id="box-holder">
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```

How could i let the user control the `transform` property of the box position to the finished spot `-200px` to `0px` only back and forth with the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

I will look into now but first a few hints.

Use document ready so your variable gets stored ones and not after each scroll.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var greySection = $('.grey').height(); 
});
```

Should the box slide to the complete right, directly in the middle or just 200px to the right? I got a little confused by the -200px.

Comment: The `.box` should move to the right 200px. It's currently offset to the left -200px from it's intended middle spot.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DenizTemizer/73y9dr72/1/ This way? Added some dynamic to it so it gets the translateX value from the CSS and works with it instead of hardcoding it into javascript.

Comment: omg yess! that's amazing! But i'll still wait for a different answer, if any. Just to see different options to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go 
https://jsfiddle.net/DenizTemizer/j6m73qnf/1/

```
var greySection;
$( document ).ready(function() {
  greySection = $('.grey').height();
  console.log(greySection);
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  if( !$('.grey').hasClass('animated') && wScroll > (greySection / 1.3) ) {
    console.log("animate");
    $('.grey').addClass('animated');
    $('.box').css({
      "-webkit-transform":"translateX(0)",
      "-ms-transform":"translateX(0)",
      "transform":"translateX(0)"
    });
  }
});
```

Added as new answer so it is easier to find if this thread gets bigger.

Comment: Sorry, I actually wanted to let the user control the `.box` back and forth with the scroll bar between `-200px` to `0px` not slide animate it forward.

Answer (score 0):

Ripped this from stuff I'm working on, then chunked it together, Dig in.

The formula you want is something like:

```
(scrollTop-topOffset)/(pageHeight-windowHeight-topOffset)*translateDistance
```

This is where it is in the JavaScript:

```
mem[7] = -(~~(((mem[0]-BoxOffset)/mem[6])*BoxDistance));
```

This needs some work, I used a right shift by zero to round the result but it was acting weird when I ran the snippet so I used the double '~~' and then had to set it to negative '-' to make it positive, don't copy/paste, fix/tidy up my chicken scratch!! XD

```js
INP=0xFFFF; // INPut flags
BoxDistance=200; // box travel distance
mem=[]; // mem array


JC = function(intv, event){


 L_BOOT:{


 L_TRIPEVENT:{


 if (!event) break L_TRIPEVENT;  // if there is an event

  event = event || window.event; // for IE
  if (event.stopPropagation) { event.stopPropagation(); } else { event.cancelBubble = true; } // stop bubble up
  FP= event.target ? event.target : event.srcElement; // get it

 if ((INP&=intv)&0x002) break L_TRIPEVENT; // if boot is complete


  INP_Resize:{

   // Save the old browser width/height dimentions? if needed ...

  if(INP&0x020) break INP_Resize; INP |= 0x020; // INP_Resize = OFF

   //
   // Get the window dimentions
   //
   mem[2] = (document.body.innerWidth)? document.body.innerWidth : document.body.clientWidth;  // window width
   mem[3] = (document.body.innerHeight)? document.body.innerHeight : document.body.clientHeight; // window height


   //
   // Get the page dimentions
   //
   mem[4]=document.getElementById('box-holder').offsetWidth;  // section width:
   mem[5]=document.getElementById('box-holder').offsetHeight*2;  // section width: (box-holder x 2) both sections are of the same height
   BoxOffset=document.getElementById('ThisTrigger').offsetHeight;  // section width:   


   mem[6]=mem[5]-mem[3]-BoxOffset; //  page height - window height = (scroll bottom)


  }// INP_Resize:


  INP_Scroll:{

   mem[1] = mem[0];  // Save last scroll location, not really needed ... 

  if(INP&0x010) break INP_Scroll; INP |= 0x010; // INP_Scroll = OFF

   mem[0] = ((document.body.scrollTop)? (document.body.scrollTop) : ((document.documentElement.scrollTop)? (document.documentElement.scrollTop):(window.pageYOffset) ));// get current scroll location

   if ( BoxOffset<mem[0] ) { // get current scroll location

    if (BoxOffset<mem[0]) {

     mem[7] = -(~~(((mem[0]-BoxOffset)/mem[6])*BoxDistance)); // right shift 0 times, un-round to a whole number

     /*
     mem[0] = scroll top -> DistanceThusFar
     BoxOffset = with the top offfset
     mem[6] = (scroll bottom) -> DistanceCanGo
     BoxDistance = distance

     (DistanceThusFar / DistanceCanGo) = (0.???)%
      the ratio between how far, and whats left to go
     (0.???) * (BoxDistance) = (???px)
      the ratio multiplied by BoxDistance is the distance
     */

     mem[7] = BoxDistance<mem[7] ? BoxDistance : mem[7]; // if the number rounded, exceeds BoxDistance, set it to BoxDistance

    }//if (mem[0]>=BoxOffse...

   } else {

    mem[7]^=mem[7]; // if the number rounded, is greater than 0, when scrollTop is less then trigger height, set it to zero

   }

   AX=mem[7];

   document.getElementById("meee").setAttribute('style', 'margin-left: '+AX+'px;'); // update box distance

  }// INP_Scroll:


 }//L_TRIPEVENT:

 if (INP&0x001) break L_BOOT; INP|=0x001; INP&=0xFFD; // L_BOOT = OFF

  INP &= 0xFEF; // 1110:1111 <- set this bit off, to trip SCROLL interupt
  INP &= 0xFDF; // 1110:1111 <- set this bit off, to trip SCROLL interupt

 }//L_BOOT:
 

  //
  // Print out memory
  //
  PrintText='';
  i=0;
  do{
   PrintText += "<br> " + i + " " + mem[i];
  i++;
  }while (i^0x08)
  document.getElementById("JC_TEST_TEXT").innerHTML = PrintText;
  PrintText^=PrintText;


TIC=setTimeout(JC,100);
}; JC();


function JCinterupts(i0,i1,i2,i3){

    if ('addEventListener' in window){
  window.addEventListener(i0, ( function (intv) {return function (event) {JC(intv, event);};} )( 0xFBF ), false);
        window.addEventListener(i1, ( function (intv) {return function (event) {JC(intv, event);};} )( 0xFEF ), false);
        window.addEventListener(i2, ( function (intv) {return function (event) {JC(intv, event);};} )( 0xFDF ), false);
        window.addEventListener(i3, ( function (intv) {return function (event) {JC(intv, event);};} )( 0xFFE ), false);
    } else if ('attachEvent' in window){//IE
        window.attachEvent('on'+i0, ( function (intv) {return function (event) {JC(intv, event);};} )( 0xFBF ) );
        window.attachEvent('on'+i1, ( function (intv) {return function (event) {JC(intv, event);};} )( 0xFEF ) );
        window.attachEvent('on'+i2, ( function (intv) {return function (event) {JC(intv, event);};} )( 0xFDF ) );
        window.attachEvent('on'+i2, ( function (intv) {return function (event) {JC(intv, event);};} )( 0xFFE ) );
    }
    
} JCinterupts('click','scroll','resize','load');
```

```html
<!--

░░█████░░░░░░░░░░░░███░░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░█░░░░░░░░░░░░░░█░░░░░░░░░█░░░░
░░░░█░░███░███░███░█░░░███░░░█░███
░░░░█░░█░█░█░█░█░░░█░░░█░█░███░█░█  JonathanClingan
░░░░█░░█░█░█░█░░░█░█░░░█░█░█░█░█░░  ©JonsCode
░░███░░███░█░█░███░███░███░███░███  5.24.16

  ■ JonWasHere :P

-->

<HTML /><!-- HTML markup -->
<HEAD /><!-- self closing tags -->

  <style>

    HTML,BODY {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      border:0;
    }
    .grey{  /* for visual purposes */
      background-color: grey;
    }
    .darkgrey{  /* for visual purposes */
      background-color: darkgrey;
      height:34px;
    }
    section {
      width:100%;
      height:134px;
    }

    p{
      width:100%;
      text-align:center;
    }
    .box{
      left:200px;
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      background-color:red;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
    #JC_TEST_HOLD{
      position:absolute;
      position:fixed;
      overflow:visible;
      padding:0 10px 0 0;
      color:white;
      z-index:900;
      text-align:left;
    }
    #JC_TEST_BOX{
      height:100%;
      overflow:auto;
      position:relative;
      margin:0;
      padding:0 15px 0 0;
      color:white;
      background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      text-align:left;
    }
    #JC_TEST_TEXT{
      text-align:left;
    }

  </style>

<BODY /><!-- Mhmmm, I like yo' body. ;) -->

  <DIV ID="JC_TEST_HOLD" >
    <DIV ID="JC_TEST_BOX" >
      <p id="JC_TEST_TEXT"></p>
    </DIV>
  </DIV>

  <section id="ThisBox" class="grey">
    <div id="ThisTrigger" class="darkgrey">
      <p>Some contents here. Ignore this section, or pay attention.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="box-holder">
    <div id="meee" class="box"></div>
  </section>
```